# SAPUI5 Mock Server - How to add a bidirectional many-to-many association

Tags: odata, sapui5

Given I have the following relationship: one project can have multiple members and one member can be assigned to multiple projects.

`Project(*)-------(*)Member`

For the first time I only want to retrieve the members that are assigned to a specific project. Here is my current oData metadata and json model configuration:

**JSON Model for Project:**

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Title": "Project 0",
        "MemberIds": [1,2]
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Title": "Project 1",
        "MemberIds": [3,4]
    }
]
```

**JSON Model for Member**

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "FirstName": "Robyn"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "FirstName": "Romero"
    }
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "FirstName": "Hattie",
    },
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "FirstName": "Chandra"
    }
]
```

**oData Metadata**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0"
            xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0"
            xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
        <Schema Namespace="NAMESPACE" xml:lang="en"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm"
                xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData">

            <EntityType Name="Member" sap:content-version="1">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" sap:label="Member Id"/>
                <Property Name="FirstName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"
                          MaxLength="255" sap:label="Member First Name" />
            </EntityType>


            <EntityType Name="Project" sap:content-version="1">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" sap:label="Project Id"/>
                <Property Name="Title" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"
                        MaxLength="255" sap:label="Project Title" />
                <Property Name="MemberIds" Type="Collection(Edm.Int32)" sap:label="Project Member Ids" />
                <NavigationProperty
                        FromRole="Project_toMembers"
                        Name="Members"
                        Relationship="NAMESPACE.ProjectToMembers"
                        ToRole="Member_toProjects" />
            </EntityType>

            <Association Name="ProjectToMembers" sap:content-version="1">
                <End Role="Project_toMembers" Multiplicity="*" Type="NAMESPACE.Project"/>
                <End Role="Member_toProjects" Multiplicity="*" Type="NAMESPACE.Member"/>
                <ReferentialConstraint>
                    <Principal Role="Project_toMembers">
                        <PropertyRef Name="MemberIds"/>
                    </Principal>
                    <Dependent Role="Member_toProjects">
                        <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
                    </Dependent>
                </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>

            <EntityContainer Name="NAMESPACE"
                             m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
                <EntitySet Name="Projects" EntityType="NAMESPACE.Project"
                           sap:pageable="false" sap:content-version="1" />
                <EntitySet Name="Members" EntityType="NAMESPACE.Member"
                           sap:pageable="false" sap:content-version="1" />
                <AssociationSet
                        Name="Project_Member"
                        Association="NAMESPACE.ProjectToMembers">
                    <End Role="Project_toMembers" EntitySet="Members" />
                    <End Role="Member_toProjects" EntitySet="Projects" />
                </AssociationSet>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

The request `http://mymockserver/Projects(1)?$expand=Members` returns the project with the given id but the attribute `members` is empty and does not contain - as expected - the member objects with the associated id's 1 and 2.

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Please use the following link to  validate your metadata. http://pragmatiqa.com/xodata/#  .  Also, I want to understand your intent behind creating JSON model when you have oData service?

Comment: Awesome link, thank you. The reason why I use JSON models is because I'm developing in a local test environment without access to a productive oData backend service.

Answer (score 1):

My guess the following is not a supported type

```
Type="Collection(Edm.Int32)"
```

take a look at [MockServer](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/util/MockServer.js#L1545) source, "Collection" doesn't seem to referenced as a type.

And it isn't listed as an allowed [OData type](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/tree/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/type), i did a quick search of the library and can only find 'Collection' referenced in DataJS.

You may still be able to cater for it in the MockServer if you [Add Your Own Requests to SAPUI5 MockServer](http://jasper07.secondphase.com.au/blog/2015/01/10/add-your-own-requests-to-sapui5-mockserver/).  Another thing I haven't as yet seen "Collections" as a type in either SAP Gateway or HANA XS, but guessing it is supported in Apache Olingo client and producer.

Comment: you're right. There is no implementation of type collection in the Mock Server. But Indepently of that I Wonder why it's not possible to add a bidirectional many to many association. I will have a look at your provided link: adding a custom request to Mock Server

Answer (score -1):

I am also trying to do something similar, but haven't managed to do so. If you look at the Cart example that comes with the UI5 SDK, you will see that they also haven't managed to do this. They get the complete entity set and then just filter the data for the selected item.

Comment: As far as I can see they have a 1:n relation between a product and a category. Check the property category used in the entity type product: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/cart/model/metadata.xml
This kind of relation is no problem - I have already implemented it. But I still don't know how to work with a m:n relation :(

Comment: From what I can see, your NavigationProperty is missing for the Member entity type. Try adding:
<NavigationProperty
         FromRole="Member_toProjects"
         Name="Projects"
         Relationship="NAMESPACE.ProjectToMembers"
         ToRole="Project_toMembers" /> to the Member EntityType